# How to reload a node with different parameters in an ExtJS TreeStore?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I tried something like this:

```
oStore.load( {
  node  : oRecord.parentNode,
  limit : 20,
  page  : nPage,
  start : 20 * nPage,
  params: {
    parent: strNodeId
  }
} );
```

But the reload doesn't happen, even after I removed all children of `oRecord.parentNodes`.

Just the `beforeload` event gets triggered, the `load` event never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if any `beforeload` callback returns `false`. This will cause the load operation to stop.

Comment: The error and success attributes of the operation object are undefined. If I put a logging function into the callback attribute it doesn't get fired. The store works with the Treepanel, but I can't get the `load()` function to work manually.

Comment: @da_b0uncer If you check the `beforeload` operation object all these properties cannot be set yet, because you have the state right before the load operation. And with callback I mean any registered listener for the `beforeload` event. If any one of these returning false or null the load operation get aborted. So you should check all `beforeload` listeners, that all of them returning true. If all that don't help post more code. It is not possible to tell what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: I see! They don't return anything. Which workes for the load() which gets called by the TreePanel. I can use the TreeStore without any problems with the TreePanel.

Comment: I got the wrong store, what is strange, because I used the `view` parameter of the `processEvent` method to get the store, which was my TreePanel view. Now I'm adding the store to the column-config of my paging-column component, which works.

Comment: @da_b0uncer As long as I could help you :) You should always take a look at the storeId which is unique between all stores that are managed within the StoreManager and that should be all them by default.